# Redirect each output of subprocess call to a different directory in different files

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, stdout, attributeerror

I have a large file which I want to split using `awk` and name it based on the value from first column.

An `awk` command on terminal would work as:

```
cat phased.MySpF1.vcf | awk '!/^#/{print>$1}'
```

thus creating separate files like 1, 2, 3 depending upon what the value of first column was.

I want put this command inside python2 file so I can store the splitted files inside another subdirectory which make accessing each chunks easy in the later part.

```
# create a directory to store the splitted files:
if os.path.exists('SplitVCF'):
    shutil.rmtree('SplitVCF', ignore_errors=False, onerror=None)
os.makedirs('SplitVCF')

# now split the vcf file
split_cmd = ['cat', vcf_path, '|', 'awk', '!/^#/{print>$1}']
subprocess.Popen(split_cmd, stdout='SplitVCF/')

#or,
subprocess.call(split_cmd, stdout='SplitVCF/')
```

But, I am getting error as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "phaser.py", line 2167, in <module>
    main();
  File "phaser.py", line 227, in main
    subprocess.Popen(split_cmd, stdout='SplitVCF/')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 386, in __init__
    errread, errwrite), to_close = self._get_handles(stdin, stdout, stderr)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 823, in _get_handles
    c2pwrite = stdout.fileno()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'fileno'
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments)

> stdin, stdout and stderr specify the executed program’s standard input, standard output and standard error file handles, respectively. Valid values are PIPE, an existing file descriptor (a positive integer), an existing file object, and None

So not a string. Instead do

```
with open('a/file/path', 'w') as out:
     subprocess.Popen(split_cmd, stdout=out)
```